# Is it possible to make this geometric figure in css and html?

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

Is it possible to make this geometric figure in css and html? Can't find anything. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: If you just want that geometric shape investigate CSS clip-path - it;s a simple polygon.

Comment: @AHaworth thanks a lot for the tip. I will read about it.

Comment: https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/

Comment: @TemaniAfif liked your answer. I didn't know about this site. Could you post this as an answer for others to see better?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also use the pseudo-classes in CSS to achieve this layout. Depending on what your overall layout looks like, try this:

```css
html {
  background-color: slategray;
}

.box-holder {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}

.cap {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cap .middle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 7px;
  width: 103%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.5%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 104%;
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2%;
  left: 0;
}

.content:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 104%;
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2%;
  right: 0;
}

.top-cap .middle:before {
  top: 0;
}

.bottom-cap .middle:before {
  bottom: 0;
}

.corner {
  width: 7.5%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.corner:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 130%;
  height: 130%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 30px solid #000;
}

.corner:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 117.5%;
  height: 117.5%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 7px solid #fff;
}

.top-cap .corner-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.top-cap .corner-left:before {
  top: -150%;
  left: -150%;
}

.top-cap .corner-left:after {
  top: -75%;
  left: -75%;
}

.top-cap .corner-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.top-cap .corner-right:before {
  top: -150%;
  right: -150%;
}

.top-cap .corner-right:after {
  top: -75%;
  right: -75%;
}

.bottom-cap .corner-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bottom-cap .corner-left:before {
  bottom: -150%;
  left: -150%;
}

.bottom-cap .corner-left:after {
  bottom: -75%;
  left: -75%;
}

.bottom-cap .corner-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bottom-cap .corner-right:before {
  bottom: -150%;
  right: -150%;
}

.bottom-cap .corner-right:after {
  bottom: -75%;
  right: -75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-holder">
  <div class="top-cap cap">
    <div class="corner-left corner"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="corner-right corner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-cap cap">
    <div class="corner-left corner"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="corner-right corner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate both EdgarReynaga and TemaniAfif response. Thanks. :)